# c++ i want to concat char but i get an segmentation fault

Tags: c++, char

I have a short question how do i concat these char in c++. I get always an segmentation fault

```
struct dirent *ent
const char *filePath = strcat("/test/",ent->d_name) ;
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the concatenated string to be stored exactly? You haven't allocated any space for it. Also, I'm assuming there's some code you haven't shown us that makes `ent` valid, otherwise you're using it before you've initialized it.

Comment: Why do you use `const char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: yes ent is init befor but i cant use an string because i need an const char

Comment: That's what the `.c_str()` function is for. (Also, that makes it seem like you didn't ask your real question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C way to concatenate strings is like this:

```
char buf[128];
strcpy(buf, "first string");
strcat(buf, "second string");
```

First we allocate space to hold the concatenated strings. Then we copy the first string into the buffer. Then we concatenate the second string onto the first.

But since you're using C++, you should really use `std::string` instead of the str* functions.

```
std::string j = "hello";
j += " there";
```

Comment: And then to get a `const char*`, just use `j.c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)?

> Appends a copy of the character string pointed to by src to the end of the character string pointed to by dest. The character src[0] replaces the null terminator at the end of dest. The resulting byte string is null-terminated.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character.

`"/test/"` is no modifiable character array in the first place, let alone "large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character".

Had you enabled a sufficiently high compiler warning level, the compiler also had told you something about passing an `const char[]` where a `char*` was expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct dirent *ent
const char *filePath = strcat("/test/",ent->d_name) ;
```

I find std::stringstream much more flexible:

```
std::stringstream filePathSS;

// streams know how to handle c-style nullterminated
filePathSS << "/test/" << ent->d_name

// and numbers
           << "_" << i++   // to create a unique file each use

// and std::string
           << "." << suffix; // append a const std::string
```

Access to const char* is trivial, via:

```
const char* filePath = filePathSS.str().c_str();
```